# how to use `localePath()` for a dynamic nuxt i18n route?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, internationalization, nuxt-i18n

I have the following route defined in my `i18n.config.js`:

```
{
 pages: {
  'rental/_id': {
    nl: '/verhuur/:id',
    en: '/rental/:id',
    de: '/mietbestand/:id',
  },
 }
}
```

In my Nuxt project I try to link to this page using `localePath()` like this:

```
<nuxt-link :to="localePath('rental/123')">
  {{ $t(item.title) }}
</nuxt-link>
```

But the above code gives following warning: `Route with name 'rental/123___nl' does not exist`

How can I link to the `rental/_id` page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using Nuxt3. First try redefining your pages like:

```
  'rental/[id]': {
    nl: '/verhuur/[id]',
    en: '/rental/[id]',
    de: '/mietbestand/[id]',
  },
```

Also, don't forget to add this to your setup:

```js
const localePath = useLocalePath()
```

If that doesn't work try doing `localePath({ name: 'rental-id', params: { id: '123' } })`